# SQLite query data that returns a Integer Array

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Hello any help would be great thank you!
i have 3 fields in my database table

```
public static final String colExpID = "ExpenseID";      
public static final String colExpExpense = "ExpenseDisc";
public static final String colExpAmount = "Amount";
```

My method to query data

```
public Integer[] queryHouse() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[]{colExpID,colExpExpense,colExpAmount};
        Integer[] Result = new Integer[]{};     
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(ExpenseTable, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        int iExpense = c.getColumnIndex(colExpExpense);
        int iAmount = c.getColumnIndex(colExpAmount);
        for(int i = 0; i < c.getCount();i++){   
            if(c.getString(iExpense) == "House"){
            Result[i] = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(iAmount));
            }
        }
        return Result;
    }
```

I'm not sure what i'm missing thank you!

Comment: I'm also not sure what you missing, since you have not specified what it is you are trying to accomplish, and how you are failing at that.

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing string with == which is NOT correct. use `equals` :

```
  if(c.getString(iExpense).equals("House")) 
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   db.execSQL("create table " + IncomeTable + " (" + colID + " Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + colIncome + " money);");
   db.execSQL("create table " +  ExpenseTable + " (" + colExpID + " Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + colExpExpense + " text, " + colExpAmount + " money);");
   
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("create table " + IncomeTable + " (" + colID + " Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + colIncome + " money);");
            db.execSQL("create table " +  ExpenseTable + " (" + colExpID + " Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + colExpExpense + " text, " + colExpAmount + " money);");

        }
```